# Use Jquery and PHP to delete a row from a table in HTML AND a Database simultaneously

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have am making a page using Ajax, Jquery, and PHP. I have gotten my table working so that when I click on a row it will set is as a 'selected' class, I have a button that says delete on it, but not sure how to link the two together.

My question is, how do I tell the button to get the id of the item in that row, send it to a pretty photo page and tell the database to delete it?

EDIT:

Here is some code:

```
// this is for the buttons

<

    div id="controlPanelSpacer"></div>

        <div id="controlPanel">
            <div id="controlPanelContent">
                <div class="btnContainer">
                    <a href="#editWindow">
                        <div id="cpEditButton" class="cpButton">
                        </div>
                        <span>Edit</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="btnContainer">
                    <a href="#deleteWindow" rel="prettyPhoto">
                        <div id="cpDeleteButton" class="cpButton">
                        </div>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a href="uploader.php" rel="facebox">Upload</a> 
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    //This is for the deleteWindow which I will be using PrettyPhoto

    <div id="deleteWindow" style="display:none">
        <div id="deleteWindow">
        <form>
            <p>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <p id="name" type="text">Are you sure you want to delete: </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This might be incredibly roundabout and not helpful at all, but iframe the table and reload it when you press delete?

Comment: This is too general, give some code examples where you are stuck or smth..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, you do an ajax call to your server that deletes it. Wait for a success reply from the server, then use jQuery to find the row and `.remove()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ajax listener in PHP and make a request to that when you click the delete button, then just simply delete the local  tags. (Ajax listener is just a normal PHP page called by a javascript (post/get) request)